# How do you declare part of a page programmaticaly

Tags: android, xml

If I have a page whose layout is designated by XML code, but I want to possibly create a few radio buttons, say, in the middle, but decide that at runtime, how would I do it? I'm new to Android so I'm taking a stab in the dark. Would something like this work?

In the XML, add a LinearLayout to the middle of the page's XML like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinLayBut"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And then in the java something like this:

```
public void setupRadioButtons(){
    LinearLayout linLay;
    linLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinLayBut);
    RadioGroup radGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
    RadioButton radBut = new RadioButton(this);
    radGroup.addView(radBut, 0);
    radGroup.setText("A button");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an efficient way to build dynamic UI. You would be better off defining the optional layout in an XML file and then inflate it when you want to use it:

```java
public void setupRadioButtons() {
    final LayoutInflater inflater =
        (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    LinearLayout buttons =
        (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.LinLayBut, null);

    LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    mainLayout.addView(buttons);
}
```

The above code assumes that the radio group and buttons are defined inside the `LinearLayout` with id `LinLayBut` and you main layout id is `main`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, but in my app, it's a one-shot setup at the beginning of the program and so efficiency doesn't matter. But more interesting for my 'education' is whether my technique will actually work or not. It sounds like your way is better, but I'd like to know if I'm starting to understand what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: It would work except that you need to add the ``RadioGroup`` as a child of the ``LinearLayout`` that you've defined by calling ``addView()`` on it. But in general it's not just an efficiency gain, but also makes for a cleaner design if you can define most (if not all) of your views in XML rather than in code. Makes it a lot easier to change things later and you have less chance of introducing bugs.

Comment: I was pretty tired when I wrote the first reply, forgetting that I don't know until runtime about the configuration of some items (in fact whether they exist at all), so I can't hardcode them in XML. I think I have to reserve a LinearLayout for them, which I hope will collapse to nothing if I don't put anything in it?

Comment: So, unluddite, would I need to say something like "linLay.addView(radGroup, 0);" - as the 4th line of the  method?

Comment: Yes, that would attach the radio group to the linear layout (you can just call ``addView(radGroup)`` without the 2nd argument if you're not trying to set up layout parameters). You then need to attach this layout to your root activity layout (the one that you pass into ``setContentView()``). Alternatively, you can attach the radio group to the root layout without creating an additional ``LinearLayout``. If you have a lot of nesting in your views, it makes the UI load slower and use up more resources, so it's best to avoid it where possible.

Comment: I don't understand your root activity layout comment. Given that the LinearLayout is already attached to the activity (because it's defined in the XML to reserve a spot for the radio buttons), wouldn't the LinearLayout already be attached and all I need to do is attach items to the Linear Layout? And you're also saying I could create the RadioGroup in place of the LinearLayout in the XML, then if I don't put any buttons (programmatically) in it, it'll just shrink to nothing?

Comment: The ``LinearLayout`` is only attached if you pass it into ``setContentView()``. If that is the case, then you're fine, but if you passed some other layout to ``setContenView()`` then you would need to attach your radio to group to that layout. I'm not sure what would happen if you have a ``RadioGroup`` with no buttons (you can just try it out), but I don't see the point of having an empty ``RadioGroup``. Might as well either add the whole thing or not at all.

Comment: The point of having an empty RadioGroup is so I can reserve space in the XML (at compile time) for an activity for radio buttons, and then determine at run-time if I need them or if I don't then the RadioGroup widget shouldn't take up any space.

Comment: That's fine, but if you end up not needing the buttons, you'll just have an empty view that still takes some time to layout and paint and takes up resources. It's up to you, but I would just create the ``RadioGroup`` on the fly if needed (and leave it out of the XML).

Comment: If I create the RadioGroup on the fly, how would I place it in the relative position I want? That's why I figured I'd create the empty RadioGroup to reserve the position, and then it'd shrink to nothing if I don't need it. Performance and resources of my app are minimal so that's not a consideration for me.

Comment: Not trying to change your implementation, just more of an FYI: you shouldn't need to reserve space because you can always programmatically insert views anywhere within the UI tree.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to unluddite, I got it to work. For those tortured souls following the thread, here's the code. The XML doesn't have a layout around it. And if I don't call the method, the radio group takes no vertical space:

```
<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/radButGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

and here's the method:

```
public void setupRadioButtons(){
RadioGroup radGroup;
radGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radButGroup);

RadioButton radBut0 = new RadioButton(this);
radGroup.addView(radBut0, 0); //2nd arg must match order of buttons
radBut0.setText("one Button");

RadioButton radBut1 = new RadioButton(this);
radGroup.addView(radBut1, 1);
radBut1.setText("Two Button");
radBut1.setChecked(true); //which button is set
```